# Parallelize CMake's `CheckCCompilerFlag`

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-flags

I use [a lot of compiler flags](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVCMake/blob/master/cmake/modules/Experimental.cmake#L347-L406) in my default builds - having CMake check all of those when it is being run from scratch takes about 10-15s on my slower laptop, which can be annoying when I'm rebuilding multiple projects from scratch or switching between `gcc` and `clang` for testing purposes.

I'm using `check_cxx_compiler_flag` to check if compiler flags are valid, and every check is run sequentially by CMake.

Assuming what CMake does is attempt to compile a dummy file passing the flag to the compiler and checking whether or not the compilation was successful, I think it would be theoretically possible to spawn multiple compiler processes to test multiple compiler flags in parallel. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to do so.

Is there a way to make CMake test compiler flags in parallel *(probably by spawning multiple compiler processes)*?

Comment: defer the checks to a shell script (dependent on the HOST_SYSTEM) which uses the host system's tricks to run the checks in parallel (on unix, append a & to the command line)

Comment: I don't think that the CMake language has any notion of concurrency.